# College assignment: Logistic regression in python

Tags: python, statistics, binary, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I have an assignment to do at university in Quantitative Methods course. We have been given a popular and well known paper where my job is to replicate some of the results from that paper. The paper is about labour market discrimination and claims to have evidence that people with white sounding names have a higher chance of getting a callback for job interview than people with African American sounding names.

I am about to do some logistic regression. My outcome variable (Y) is callbacks and my predictor variable (x) can be many things like race, number of previous job, gender, years of job experience and so on. I have already done the regression for white sounding names and callbacks and i have done all the work on dummy variables, binary variable and so on. Now I need to run the model again with a new variable together with race, which is years of job experience.

My first regression run (which is fine and i understand the results):

```
log_odds_call = smf.logit("call ~ race_w",
    data = df2_cat).fit()
```

I just dont understand this line of code that my teacher told us to use when adding more x variables:

```
log_ods_call_yearsexp_interaction = smf.logit('call ~ race_w + yearsexp + race_w:yearsexp', data = df2_cat).fit()
```

What does that colon between race_w and yearsexp mean and why should i use it? I mean i have already added yearsexp - why do that colon thing at the end?
My outcome is this:
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq9Mg.png)

Comment: From the statsmodels [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html#multiplicative-interactions): *“:” adds a new column to the design matrix with the product of the other two columns*

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher suggests adding an interaction term in your model by multiplying those two columns. That idea is based on the thought that increasing the first variable may also increase the impact of the second variable, leading to a higher slope for the latter. In other words, when two variables get into the model, a synergy occurs, which is referred to as "interaction effect". Probably, your teacher wanted to consider such a synergy between those two variables.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for adding the "interaction effect" to my vocabulary, because i had no term for it and therefore not a chance of looking it up myself.